# Azure TLS mutual authentication X-ARR-ClientCert not found

Tags: asp.net, azure, mutual-authentication

Hello i did followed how to configure TLS Mutual Authentication as described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/bs-latn-ba/azure/app-service/app-service-web-configure-tls-mutual-auth) , i checked also that my clientCertEnabled is enabled on my backend application by checking my ressource in https://resources.azure.com : `"clientCertEnabled": true,` ,usually as described in MSDN implementation that should add a Header called :  **X-ARR-ClientCert** but here is the list of headers i'm getting and there is no **X-ARR-ClientCert** :

```
Connection, Accept, Accept-Encoding, Authorization, Host, Max-Forwards, User-Agent, X-UserId, Request-Id, X-WAWS-Unencoded-URL,CLIENT-IP, X-ARR-LOG-ID, DISGUISED-HOST, X-SITE-DEPLOYMENT-ID, WAS-DEFAULT-HOSTNAME, X-Original-URL, X-Forwarded-For, X-ARR-SSL, X-Forwarded-Proto,X-AppService-Proto, ApplicationInsights-RequestTrackingTelemetryModule-RootRequest-Id
```

i'm totally lost here .